# Visual Studio 2017 tells me a Visual Studio 2019 version is now available every time I open the IDE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019

This just started today: whenever I open an instance of the VS 2017 IDE, I get a yellow bar informing me of a new version of Visual Studio 2019, which pushes down the existing windows thus reducing the visible area of the windows.

[image]

I don't have or use VS 2019, and at this moment in time I don't care about its new versions.  The first time it happened I clicked the "x" thinking that would be the end of it, and when it did it again I clicked "More info" with the same result.  How do I stop this?

Posts like [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/30edc7af-c696-459a-a439-70d137e04faf/how-to-disable-automatic-updates-in-vs-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral) erroneously point people to the "Tools | Options | Environment | Extensions and Update" which, as the OP notes, is about updates to *extensions*, not the IDE.

Comment: @HansPassant I [also get this each day](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvxbr21runcld59/VS2017_Updateto2019Screen.png?dl=0)

Comment: Even if you install VS2019, login with your account, VS2017 will keep showing this annyoing message.

Answer (score 0):

I've developed an extension for Visual Commander: [Block Visual Studio 2019 installation prompts in VS 2017](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/code/Block%20Visual%20Studio%202019%20installation%20prompts%20(VS%202017).vcmd).

But these messages all stopped to appear by themselves today on my machine...